# Building a table of numbers within a FOR LOOP

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I have below procedure which I need to call from another procedure.

```
PROCEDURE get_list_ntds_for_given_port(
  pis_olt_name       IN common.types.string
, pis_chasis_lt_port IN common.types.string
, pona_ntd_ids       OUT common_api.ntabtype
)
IS
  lsa_object_name       common_api.vtabtype;
  lsa_link_type         common_api.vtabtype;
  lsa_link_status       common_api.vtabtype;
  lna_link_object_id    common_api.ntabtype;
  lsa_link_object_name  common_api.vtabtype;
  lsa_link_object_class common_api.vtabtype;
  ln_pon_port_id        NUMBER;
  lna_child_pon_result  FLS_NUMBER_TABLE;
  lona_ntd_ids          common_api.ntabtype;
  ls_pon_port_map       common.types.string;
BEGIN
  ls_pon_port_map := pis_olt_name || '/' || pis_chasis_lt_port;
  ln_pon_port_id := nwmdl.alu_pon_port.find(
      pis_full_pon_port_name => ls_pon_port_map
    );
  lna_child_pon_result:= rm.sri_object_utils.get_child_objects(
      pis_proc_name => lc_proc_name
    , pin_parent_id => ln_pon_port_id
    );
    pona_ntd_ids := common_api.ntabtype();
  FOR i IN 1..lna_child_pon_result.COUNT
  LOOP
    rm.ims_objects_api.get_peer_links (
        pin_object_id          => lna_child_pon_result(i)
      , pis_geographical_only  => 'N'
      , pona_object_id         => lona_ntd_ids
      , posa_object_name       => lsa_object_name
      , posa_link_type         => lsa_link_type
      , posa_link_status       => lsa_link_status
      , pona_link_object_id    => lna_link_object_id
      , posa_link_object_name  => lsa_link_object_name
      , posa_link_object_class => lsa_link_object_class
      ); 
    pona_ntd_ids.EXTEND(lona_ntd_ids.COUNT);
    FOR i IN 1..lona_ntd_ids.COUNT 
    LOOP 
      pona_ntd_ids(i) := lona_ntd_ids(i);
    END LOOP;  
  END LOOP;
END get_list_ntds_for_given_port;
```

I simulate the external call with this pl-sql block:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
lona_ntd_ids common_api.ntabtype;
BEGIN
svcmgr_lni.design_and_assign.get_list_ntds_for_given_port( pis_olt_name        =>  'SWOLT0000003DV'
                              ,pis_chasis_lt_port =>  '1-1/LT1/1'
                              ,pona_ntd_ids       => lona_ntd_ids
                             );
     FOR i IN 1..lona_ntd_ids.COUNT 
      LOOP                       
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lona_ntd_ids(i)); 
      END LOOP; 
 END;
```

The problem is that I don't get any result in the output.
My guess is that my `rm.ims_objects_api.get_peer_links` API will be called for every `lna_child_pon_result(i)` found by `rm.sri_object_utils.get_child_objects`and will put in the OUT param of the API more exactly in every output parm a table of numbers(ids) or varchar.
What I want to achive is to build the table of numbers of the main PROCEDURE(`get_list_ntds_for_given_port`) and set it to the output parameter so to use that table of numbers outside the main procedure.
Please leave any ideas that you have on solving this.

Comment: This will probably not solve your problem - but in the inner loop "pona_nt_ids(i)" will start with i=1 for every outer loop. Is that intentional?

Comment: What is the definition of common_api.ntabtype?

Comment: To answer your first question: no it was not intentional, changed that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Move "pona_ntd_ids := common_api.ntabtype();" outside the loops:

```
pona_ntd_ids := common_api.ntabtype();
FOR i IN 1..lna_child_pon_result.COUNT
```

Change

```
pona_ntd_ids(i) := lona_ntd_ids(i);
```

to

```
pona_ntd_ids(pona_ntd_ids.COUNT+1) := lona_ntd_ids(i);
```

Since in your original code you initialize pona_ntd_ids for every loop you will end up with nothing if the last outer iteration yields lona_ntd_ids.COUNT=0.

Comment: Second change raise `Subscription beyond count` error. Thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: Setting this line `pona_ntd_ids(pona_ntd_ids.COUNT+1) := lona_ntd_ids(i);`  to this `pona_ntd_ids(pona_ntd_ids.COUNT) := lona_ntd_ids(i);`  seems to do the trick

Comment: Oh yes - I forgot about the explicit use of EXTEND - which is perhaps needed depending on the definition of common_api.ntabtype :-)

Comment: `create or replace
TYPE              "NTABTYPE"                                          AS TABLE OF  NUMBER;`

Comment: So the type of ntabtype is table of number

Comment: Ok - then the explicit EXTEND is needed. If the definition had included e.g. `INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER` you would not need to initialize and extend it explicitly. If you found my answer useful I would appreciate if you flagged it as correct by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer:-)

Answer (score 1):

Lilte modification you can do and bulk collect the whole object and then make it as OUT param. Yes this will be a overhead on program as Regex is used but it will suffice your query.

```
FOR i IN 1..lona_ntd_ids.COUNT 
    LOOP 
    lv_eg_string := lona_ntd_ids(i)||','||lv_eg_string;
--      pona_ntd_ids(i) := lona_ntd_ids(i);
    END LOOP; 
    lv_eg_string:=substr(lv_eg_string,1,length(lv_eg_string)-1);
    SELECT regexp_substr(lv_eg_string,'[^,]+', 1, level) BULK COLLECT
    INTO pona_ntd_ids
    FROM dual
   CONNECT BY regexp_substr(lv_eg_string, '[^,]+', 1, level);
```

Comment: Is that much overhead brought by Regex?

Comment: Yes it can but if data volume is less we wont need to worry much about it :)

Comment: Ok, I'll look on the performance of both answers and take a decision on what to use, thank you very much